# How do I get my Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I discovered the Pokemon Global Link site, and got a few different Pokemon in the Dream World, which was neat.

I have no idea, however, to actually get them in game. The game mentions I have to go somewhere and talk to someone, but I have no idea who or where.

I am relatively early in the game (I am currently in the Pinwheel Forest), so I might not have access to wherever I need to be to get my Pokemon, which is fine, but when will I be able to get to where I have to go?

Comment: [Entralink](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Entralink) and [Dream World](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Dream_World) at Bulbapedia, for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the C-Gear's wireless function, you want to look for the Entralink. This will teleport you to a physical location in the game world that can only be accessed via the C-gear; it's counter-intuitive, but it's basically like the Underground from gen4. In this area, you'll have the option to catch pokemon befriended from the Dream World. This lets you capture them in whatever ball you want rather than being forced into using a standard pokeball. They're willing to be caught, it's not difficult.